# How to get two string variables passed from the base .cshtml page into the .cs page and the partial view?

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, fetch-api, asp.net-core-3.1

I have this in my base.cshtml page:

[image]

I then have this in the base.cs

[image]

The partial view is as such:

[image]

How do I get the strings (`testing` and `testing2`) into base.cs and then into the partial view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a value from JS code to server-side code using query strings. In your case:

```js
.fetch('testpage/?handler=TestPartial&' + 
  new URLSearchParams({ testing, testing2 }))
```

This will request the URL `testpage/?handler=TestPartial&testing=xxx&testing2=yyy`

You need to declare those parameters in your server-side method to parse and receive them:

```cs
public PartialViewResult OnGetTestPartial(string testing, string testing2)
{
  ...
}
```

Your parameters will be passed to your method this way. To show these parameters in the view, you need to pass it as a model to the view:

```cs
public class TestPartialViewModel
{
  public string Testing { get; set; }
  public string Testing2 { get; set; }
}

public partial ViewResult OnGetTestPartial(string testing, string testing2)
{
  return Partial("Partials/TestPartial", new TestPartialViewModel 
  { 
    testing, 
    testing2
  });
}
```

and declare your viewmodel class as the model for your view at the top of your view:

```
@model TestPartialViewModel

The value of testing is @Model.Testing
The value of testing2 is @Model.Testing2
```

Comment: How do I send it to the partial view to display? Thanks for this answer!

Comment: @cdub You pass it in a viewmodel. I edited my answer to cover that. You're welcome :)

Comment: Yes I figured out just before you posted this. Thanks, this helps a lot.